# IOS Swift: Load new url to a webview after receiving a push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, webview

I have a Swift 2.0 app with a webview and push notification.
The Webview is working every time the app starts.

After receving a push notifications, i need to call another url. 
(to react on the push message)

How can I access the webview element in my appdelegate function didReceiveRemoteNotification ? Is this possible?

My Code so far:

```
ViewController:
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate { 
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView.delegate = self;

        var urlStringHost = "http://www.exampleUrl.com"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlStringHost)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Delegate:

```
// Push Empfangen
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("push empfangen")
    print(userInfo)
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0


    // Load some new url to the existing webview (not working)
    //webview?.loadRequest(request)




}
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using NSNotificationCenter , you can do it.

First set notification and set selector in your viewcontroller.

```
func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add observer for load request in webview when receive remote notification.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"PushReceiver:", name: "PushReceived", object: nil)
}

//When post notification then below method is called.
func PushReceiver(notifi: NSNotification) 
{
    var dicNotifi: [NSObject : AnyObject] = notifi.userInfo
    NSLog("notificiation Info %@ \n", dicNotifi)
}
```

When receive remote notification then post notification in didReceiveRemoteNotification method from AppDelegate Class.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]) 
{
    print("push empfangen")
    print(userInfo)
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    //post notification.
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PushReceived", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Hello, this is exactly what i was searching for. So i can handle the request after a push event in the controller with your solution and not in the delegate. This is perfect. Many Thanks.

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you then please consider marking the answer as correct so that other people can find the answer quickly.

Comment: I did, but its only valid when i reached a reputaion of 15. (I am new here)

Comment: You can approve it. see this link for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts. By approving it other people can find the answer quickly.

Comment: Okay, i marked it as accepted answer now. Only voting up is not working until 15 Reputation :) Again, thank you for the information